# Ajax Post and retrieve multiple variables

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, ajax

I need help on how to post and retrieve multiple variables using Ajax Post. I actually needed to retrieve the posted  variables for SQL query. See below the Ajax Code where i needed to include variable names selschool, selprogram, selsession to the post

```
<script>

    $("#session").change(function()
    {
        $("#loding2").show();
        var id=$(this).val();
        var dataString = 'id='+ id;
        var selschool=document.getElementById("selectedschool").val();
        var selprogram=document.getElementById("selectedprogram").val();
        var selsession=document.getElementById("selectedsession").val();

        $("#semester").find('option').remove();
        $("#class").find('option').remove();
        document.getElementById("selectedclass").value= " ";
        document.getElementById("selectedsemester").value= " ";
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_class.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
                $("#loding2").hide();
                $("#class").html(html);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Also see below PHP script where i wanted to use the posted variable for the query;

```
 <?php
include('dbconfig.php');
if($_POST['id'])
{
    $id=$_POST['id'];

//  Todo: I actually needed something like where session SELECT * FROM class where session_id=$id and program_id="selprogram" and school_id="selschool"
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM class where session_id=$id ");
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));

    ?><option selected="selected">Select Class :</option>
    <?php while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['class_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['class_name']; ?></option>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `data: {id: id, selprogram: selprogram, selschool: selschool},`

Comment: @Jeff You beat me to it hehe

Comment: Im not so fluent in php, but it looks like this would also create a SQL Injection vulnerability, unless PDO::FETCH_ASSOC does some magic?

Comment: Thanks Jeff, but how will i access the variables from he PHP page?

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain the solution
consider the ajax call to demo.php

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'demo.php',
  type: 'post',
  data: {
    'name': 'abc',
    'phone': '1234567899'
  }, //data is in json form
  success: function(res) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(res)); //parsing because we will pass the data from demo.php in encoded form you will get it.
  }
});
```

now in demo.php you will access data as $_POST['name'] and $_POST['phone']. lets pass the same to ajax call. will store it in array and will pass it.

```
<?php
  $Arr = [];
  $Arr[0] = $_POST['name'];
  $Arr[1] = $_POST['phone'];
  echo json_encode($Arr); 
?>
```

like this, we can pass data to ajax and can pass the data from PHP file to request.
Hope that you got the result. Thank you.